# Modx IF return blank page

Tags: php, date, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to check server date and time to compate with date TV of resource, but i always get blank page when I try to check in IF statment, here is what i need.

I have snippet like this

```
<?php
function getDatetimeNow() {
  $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Belgrade');
  $datetime = new DateTime();
  $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
  return $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');
}

$currentDate = getDatetimeNow();

$dtA = new DateTime($currentDate);
$dtB = new DateTime($date);

if ( $dtA > $dtB ) {
  $active = 0;
  return $active;
}
else {
  $active = 1;
  return $active;
}
```

But when on page if i try like this

```
[[!CheckCurrentDate? &date=`[[*DatumIsteka]]`]]
```

I got 1 or 0 based on TV value *DatumIsteka, all is working ok, but when i try to compare like this

```
[[!If?
    &subject=`[[!CheckCurrentDate? &date=`[[*DatumIsteka]]`]]`
    &operator=`equals`
    &operand=`0`
    &then=`<script>
    $("#tab3").html("<p>U Pripremi</p>");
    </script>`
    ]]
```

I got white page of resource??
What can be the problem, any help will be nice :)

Comment: Check out apache errors logs.

Comment: Anything in MODX error log?

Answer (score 0):

change your operator to not equal and your operand to 1 - modx TVs don't actually exist unless they are populated [even if they have a default defined] you may be getting a null value or error in your snippet if the TV is not populated.

OR

echo your return value,

```
if ( $dtA > $dtB ) {
  $active = 0;
}
else {
  $active = 1;
}

echo $active;

return;
```

IF may be having issues interpreting the return values as boolean vs. string?

You can also change your snippet to retrieve the current resources DatumIsteka value and then use [output modifiers](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)).

or something like this:

```
<?php
function getDatetimeNow() {
  $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Belgrade');
  $datetime = new DateTime();
  $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
  return $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');
}

$currentDate = getDatetimeNow();

$dtA = new DateTime($currentDate);

$date = $modx->resource->getTVValue('DatumIsteka');

$dtB = new DateTime($date);

if ( $dtA > $dtB ) {
  $active = $modx->getChunk('chunkName');
// chunkName = <script>$("#tab3").html("<p>U Pripremi</p>");</script>
}
else {
  $active = 1;
}

echo $active; // you have to echo it if you are passing a string

return;
```